# Unit testing .Net core 6 with injected logger

Tags: c#, logging, dependency-injection, extension-methods, nlog

I am in the process of wrapping NLog and writing up some unit tests to check that NLog is registered as a service within the `ILoggingBuilder`. I register NLog using their extension method which extends the `ILoggingBuilder`:

```
ILoggingBuilder Builder
Builder.AddNLog(config);
```

Obviously because this is a static extension method I can't test mock this and verify it's been called so I've resigned myself to the fact that I will need to test around it to assert that NLog has been registered as a logging service provider.

This is where I'm stuck. So far I have mocked the `ILoggingBuilder` and setup a service collection:

```
//Arrange
var mockLoggingBuilder = new Mock<ILoggingBuilder>();
var config = new MyLoggerConfiguration();
var factory = new NLogFactory(config, mockLoggingBuilder.Object);
var mockServiceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
mockLoggingBuilder.SetupGet(x => x.Services).Returns(mockServiceCollection);
mockLoggingBuilder.Setup(x => x.Services).Returns(mockServiceCollection);


//Act
factory.SetupProvider();

//Assert
var services = mockLoggingBuilder.Object.Services;
services.Count.Should().Be(1,
"nlog should have been added as a logging service with the call of SetupProvider on the factory.");
var configuredServices = services.GetEnumerator();
configuredServices.MoveNext();
var currentService = configuredServices.Current;
```

But I now can't figure out how to assert that this service is of the nlogger type.

Anyone able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: You are essentially trying to test their code. Ideally they would have done that already before release. Anyhow, you could check their publicly available source code to see how they test that extension. https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/blob/39b4fd022454471b49f432a3105d0547e379e5c8/test/NLog.Extensions.Logging.Tests/Extensions/ConfigureExtensionsTests.cs

Comment: Please can you add this as an answer as i'd like to upvote you - thank you for the suggestion - I'm mad I didn't think of it myself :D